# Duplicating values down for each "matching value" in a separate column

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm looking for an automated process that will let me replicate an identification number down against a list of reference numbers in a separate column. Every time the identification number changes in column B, it would need to repeat in every box below it until a new identification number is listed.

I've provided the existing data structure, and the requested format color coded to better showcase what is needed in the example at the link below:

[image: 0]

**[DEMO FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-RLsAIccfzzQhWuS2q-6Abknk9jhpdYBYTmBJzw5ahA/edit#gid=0)!**

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Identification Number"; 
 IF(LEN(C4:C), VLOOKUP(ROW(B4:B), FILTER({ROW(B4:B), B4:B}, LEN(B4:B)), 2), )})
```

[image: 0]